How do I center the caption of an Pygame Window?
I want to make a very beautiful Program, The Program already looks very good, but The Only Thing which annoys me is, that the window caption (window title) isn't centered.
Does anyone know how I can achieve this?
I know you can paint a custom anything, but I also read that this is very complicated and this way mentioned isn't working on Windows 10 anymore.
I really need help, because the Program is very good and also looks already very good but I just need to do this little Thing.
I tried to center the Title and were expecting that its gonna be easy, but it's pretty hard. Not as hard as the Speech To Speech System of my program with the custom voice, but still very hard.

on Linux it depends on theme which you set in system. But frankly I don't care if it is centered or not. It waste of time.

the only idea: maybe you can create borderless window and draw title directly on PyGame screen. python - Pygame borderless opening with some offset - Stack Overflow

I agree with furas' comments that this is highly subject to your desktop windows manager and using a borderless window and drawing your own title will get you the aesthetic you seem to desire.
If you want centred text, your can always use the built-in str.center() function to pad your string. However the width parameter is the character length, so you'll need to convert that to pixels based on your window width. Your window manager probably won't display leading or trailing whitespace, so you might need to bookend your centred string in printable characters.
Here's a minimal example:
import pygame

def set_centred_title(window, title):
    title_width = window.get_width()
    title_columns = round(title_width / 13.4)  # Magic Number!
    fill_character = chr(0x2001)  # Unicode EM QUAD
    # add non-space characters at each end to prevent whitespace strip.
    padded_title = f"-{title:{fill_character}^{title_columns}}-"
    pygame.display.set_caption(padded_title) 

pygame.init()

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 900, 500
initial_title = "Centred Title"

window = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT), pygame.RESIZABLE)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
set_centred_title(window, initial_title)
running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        if event.type == pygame.VIDEORESIZE:  # size, w, h
            set_centred_title(window, "Resized Centred Title")
            
    window.fill("black")
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(30)
pygame.quit()

For me this looks okay:

However it will probably be broken on a different PC with different settings.
